# Change color of text using css

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can the color of this text be changed as it is inputted by the user in the text box through css only..

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" />
```

Comment: Changed conditionally? No, but you can set the colour of the text in the textbox with :focus pseudo-class. You might want to clarify exactly what you want to change, but if it's a validation thing you will need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Do you mean to have it change colour _while_ the user types in text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested, but wouldn't it just be:

```
input {color:blue}
```

Comment: Note, I think  id-"name1" should be id="id1". note the equals sign. Also ina number of cases ID and NAME share the same namespace and so can't be the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
input:focus {color:blue}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting your question like this:
You want to change the text color in text box to the color name that has been typed into that text box.

if my interpretation is right then, following jQuery snippet will do the thing:

```
$("#name1").css("color", $("#name1").text());
```