# Unable to create text color within <th> tag in html and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to color Name and Salary in white within `<th>` tag. Also need background color for `<th>` is green. I have done background color in green but unbale to color my text in white. My code is given below:

```html
<table style="width:90%"; border= 1px solid black;>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#0C7D18"; colspan="2">Name</th>
    <th style="background-color:#0C7D18";>Salary</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Unable to create text color for Name and Salary in white within `<th>` tag.

Comment: You should use "color" to change color of your text

Comment: <table style="width:90%"; border= 1px solid black;>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#0C7D18;color:#FFF;" colspan="2">Name</th>
    <th style="background-color:#0C7D18;color:#FFF">Salary</th>
  </tr>

Comment: Its works perfect. Great Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of text using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650177/change-color-of-text-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more problems than just the header color and background.   Your table element syntax is wrong.

- Remove the quote after `90%`
- Replace the `=` after `border` with a colon `:`
- Put quote after the end of your style `black;">`
- Add white to your headers  `color:#FFFFFF;`

I revised the markup to include the `thead` and `tbody` and added some rows to allow a clear visual of the results.

I also put a second example in using CSS which for many circumstances is a better way to style things than in-line.  For example if you have 10 header you would only need one place to change it not 10, and makes the markup a bit cleaner.

```html
<table style="width:90%; border:1px solid black;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color:#0C7D18; color:#FFFFFF" colspan="2">Name</th>
      <th style="background-color:#0C7D18; color:#FFFFFF">Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>three</td>
      <td>up the</td>
      <td>hill</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
.my-table {
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.my-header {
  background-color: #0C7D18;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="my-header" colspan="2">Name</th>
      <th class="my-header">Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>three</td>
      <td>up the</td>
      <td>hill</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`background-color`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) is used to set the color of the background.

Use [`color`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp) to target **text color**;

```html
<table style="width:90%"; border= 1px solid black;>
  <tr>
    <th style="color:white; background-color:#0C7D18"; colspan="2">Name</th>
    <th style="color:white; background-color:#0C7D18";>Salary</th>
  </tr>
```